# Passing the class name dynamically to clazz parameter in BTrace script

Tags: java, jvm, btrace

I need to pass application's package name to btrace script to clazz parameter dynamically when I attach the agent to the jvm .How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible in the current version 1.3.10.2

Please, check https://github.com/btraceio/btrace/issues/298 where this feature is implemented.